# Pandas crosstab on multiindex

Tags: pandas, multi-index, crosstab

Hi I am trying to get Crosstab from a multi index variable "df" :

df.tail()

```
code    X1  X2  X3
pays    USA USA USA
desc    phase   phase   phase
2020-01-01  a   a   a
2020-02-01  b   c   d
2020-03-01  a   a   b
2020-04-01  c   a   a
2020-05-01  d   a   d
```

I would like to get something like :

```
             X1                X2           X3
       a   b   c   d       a  b  c  d    a  b  c  d

    a
X1  b 
    c 
    d                          
    a
X2  b 
    c
    d
    a
X3  b
    c 
    d
```

where in each cell I get the number / percentage of Xi, Xj value of (a,b,c,d)

I tried :

```
pd.crosstab(index = df, columns = df)
```

but I get an error message :

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 2), indices imply (605, 2)
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: does your original data have a 3-level columns?

Comment: Yes. My df has a multi index structure with 3 levels

Comment: fill in the blanks for ur expected output

Comment: I would like to have a contingency table ie the number / percentage of variable that are simultaneously (a,a), (a,b)...for each (XI, Xj)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a way to do this with the `pd.crosstab` function, but its possible via a double loop.  I'd love for this to work with ordered (Categorical) types, but my naive attempt, commented out, did not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def full_crosstab(df, row_keys=None, col_keys=None):
    row_keys = row_keys or df.columns
    col_keys = col_keys or df.columns
    df_final = []
    for outer in row_keys:
        df_outer = []
        for inner in col_keys:
            df_inner = pd.crosstab(df[outer], df[inner])
            df_outer.append(df_inner)
        df_outer = pd.concat(df_outer, axis=1, keys=col_keys)
        df_final.append(df_outer)
    return pd.concat(df_final, keys=row_keys)


def category(values, size):
    series = np.random.choice(values, size=size)
    return pd.Series(series)
    #dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(categories=values, ordered=True)
    #return pd.Series(series, dtype=dtype)

size = 100
mydf = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    age_range=category(['<18', '18-34', '35-64', '65+'], size=size),
    reg=category(['yes', 'no'], size=size),
    issue=category(['guns', 'schools', 'healthcare'], size=size),
))


df_ct = full_crosstab(mydf)
print(df_ct)
```

```
                     age_range               reg     issue                   
                         18-34 35-64 65+ <18  no yes  guns healthcare schools
age_range 18-34             22     0   0   0  14   8     8          7       7
          35-64              0    24   0   0  10  14    11         10       3
          65+                0     0  23   0  13  10     9          5       9
          <18                0     0   0  31  17  14     5         14      12
reg       no                14    10  13  17  54   0    13         19      22
          yes                8    14  10  14   0  46    20         17       9
issue     guns               8    11   9   5  13  20    33          0       0
          healthcare         7    10   5  14  19  17     0         36       0
          schools            7     3   9  12  22   9     0          0      31
```